# what is mean by contex free not regular

Tags: finite-automata

I am preparing contex free grammar for an exam. I couldn't understand why the language

```
{ a^n b^n | n>=0}
```

is context free but not regular. Why is it not regular?
When can we say that an expression is not regular?

Thanks

Comment: may be this is exams season; recently such questions asked on SO

Answer (score 3):

An expression is not regular if it cannot be matched (exactly) by a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or (equivalently) a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). See also [context free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) and [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Answer (score 3):

Like said in previous answers, its context free because you can express it with context free grammar.

For example: [S -> aSb | ε](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Example_3)

Its not regular because you cannot express it with finite state machine nor regular expressions. You should be able to count the number of As and check that number of Bs match. This cannot be done with finite states as *n* could be anything

Comment: Exactly! No need for the pumping lemma

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to use the [Pumping Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can say it is context free because you can express it using a Context-Free Grammar. It is not regular however because a regular expression (and finite automata) can not represent that language.